# Как сделать простую хеш-функцию, которая соответствует критерию из вопроса?

Tags: c, хеширование

Привет. Я пытаюсь сгенерировать для набора из `M` разных строк отличающиеся хеш-значения, которые при этом меньше заданного числа `K`, которое в несколько раз больше `M`.

Делаю следующим образом: добавляю к строке `salt`. Если обнаруживается коллизия, меняю `salt`.

Беда в том, что для моей хеш-функции (код ниже) и некоторых строк, видимо, выполняется условие (псевдоязык):

```
hash(a) % K == hash(b) % K
=>
hash(concat(salt, a)) % K == hash(concat(salt, b)) % K
```

Я пробовал `crc32` из `zlib` - та же беда. В общем, нужна **простая** хеш-функция, для которой это условие не выполняется. Функции MD5 и SHA* - **сложные**.

Нижеприведенный код генерирует `M` разных случайных строк, при этом пытается найти такое значение `salt`, чтобы между `hash(concat(salt, string)) % K` не было коллизий. Но, начиная с некоторого значения `M`, попадаются две такие строки, что результат `hash(...) % K` для них одинаковый, независимо от значения `salt`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// количество строк
#define M 600

// максимальная длина строки, учитывая 0 в конце
#define N 20

// предельное значение хеш-функции+1
#define K 4096

char strings[M][N];

unsigned hash(unsigned result, unsigned char *string, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result += (result << 3) + string[i];
    return result;
}

uint64_t salt = 0;

int main()
{
    int i, j, len, regenerate, collision;
    unsigned hash1, hash2;

    // генерация случайных строк
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {

        // случайная длина строки
        len = 1 + random() % (N-1);

        char tmpstr[N];

        // генерация случайной строки
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
            tmpstr[j] = 'a' + random() % 26;
        tmpstr[len] = 0;

        // проверка, нет ли уже такой строки
        regenerate = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (strcmp(tmpstr, strings[j]) != 0) continue;
            regenerate = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (regenerate) {
            // такая строка уже есть; начать этот шаг цикла повторно
            i--;
            continue;
        } else {
            // записать новую строку в массив
            strcpy(strings[i], tmpstr);
        }

        // найти salt, при котором нет коллизий
        do {
            // хеш сгенерированной строки
            hash1 = hash(0, (unsigned char*)&salt, sizeof(salt));
            hash1 = hash(hash1, (unsigned char*)tmpstr, len);
            hash1 %= K;

            // проверка, нет ли уже строки с таким хеш-значением
            collision = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                // хеш строки из массива
                hash2 = hash(0, (unsigned char*)&salt, sizeof(salt));
                hash2 = hash(hash2, (unsigned char*)strings[j], strlen(strings[j]));
                hash2 %= K;
                if (hash1 != hash2) continue;
                collision = 1;
                printf("COLLISION: %s[%d] (%u) %s[%d] (%u)\n", tmpstr, i, hash1, strings[j], j, hash2);
                salt++;
                break;
            }
        } while (collision);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Может быть, код содержит ошибки. Может быть, я не понимаю чего-то важного. Может быть, даже для MD5 все будет так же. В общем, помогите, please.

Comment: Зачем, если фиксированные строки можно просто сложить в map и в качестве хэша использовать номера оттуда?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, можно. Например, примерно так делает интерпретатор LUA (интернинг строк). Но мне показалась интересной задача из вопроса, поэтому я его опубликовал.

Comment: Указанное псевдоусловие будет выполняться практически для всех хэш-функций, так как они держат некоторое внутреннее состояние, обновляя его по мере проглатывания данных. Все, чего вы добиваетесь добавлением соли - это то, что это состояние будет отличаться от исходного, но все равно будет совпадать для одинакового префикса.

Comment: @etki, если это совершенно точно так, то это хороший ответ на вопрос, и если вы его оформите в виде ответа на вопрос, то я выберу его лучшим.

Comment: @etki это верно только в случае, когда префикс равняется длине блока хеш-функции. А так как соль здесь всего 4 байта, то псевдоусловие никак не выполняется автоматически для нормальных хеш-функций с длиной блока 64+ байта.

Comment: @Zergatul верно -_-

Comment: @Zergatul, соль тут 8 байт, а не 4, но это в принципе не важно. Беда в том, что для одних строк получается разное значение hash при изменении соли, а для других - никак. Так же было и с crc32 (пользовался версией из zlib)

Comment: @AlexanderZonov я подозреваю, это потому что операция `% 4096` фактически значит взять 12 бит из числа. Если взять не степень 2 возможно ситуация изменится, так как будет учитываться каждый бит.

Comment: @Zergatul, взял K=4097. Для M=600 уже не работает (бесконечный цикл).

Comment: @AlexanderZonov хеш-функция очень плохая. Если вы будете генерировать строки с минимальной длиной 11, то не будет ситуации, когда соль не меняет хеш. 11 потому что хеш функция обновляет только 3*(длину данных) бит. 32бита/3=11.

Comment: @Zergatul, да, плохая функция, это я понимаю. Но с crc32 была примерно такая же ситуация, а crc32 хорошая функция. Вопрос, собственно, и заключается в том, какую функцию вы мне посоветуете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для произвольного набора строк, что для  MD5 (или SHA), что для любой другой фиксированной функции, если  возьмете остаток от деления на N (ведь ваши коды должны быть меньше N), то все равно возможны коллизии.

Однако, если набор строк фиксирован, то задача решаема.

Посмотрите на статью [Perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) и [GNU gperf is a perfect hash function generator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно взять несколько приемов с реальных хеш-функций, и сделать простой лавинный эффект. В меня получилось как-то так (псевдокодом):

```
int hash(int result, byte[] data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        result += 0xBB67AE85;
        // разбиваем result на байты: b
        byte b0 = b[0] ^ rotateleft(result, b[1] + (data[i] & 0xAA)));
        byte b1 = b[1] ^ rotateleft(result, b[2] + (data[i] & 0x55)));
        byte b2 = b[2] ^ rotateleft(result, b[3] - (data[i] & 0xAA)));
        byte b3 = b[3] ^ rotateleft(result, b[0] - (data[i] & 0x55)));
        b0 += 0x6A;
        b1 += 0x09;
        b2 += 0xE6;
        b3 += 0x67;
        // собираем b0,b1,b2,b3 обратно в result
    }
    return result;
}
```

Константы взяты с `SHA256`, `0xAA = 10101010b`, `0x55 = 01010101b`. Работает быстро, находит даже при `M=1200`, `K=4096`.